# WCF Silverlight HTTP AND HTTPS

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I've got a Silverlight app that I want to call from either https or http. 
I've got it working with one or the other but am having problems making it work with both (with a single web.config)

I've found a post on silverlight.net forums that shows how they did it but it is not working for me. http://silverlight.net/forums/t/13275.aspx (the post marked as the answer)

Am I missing something?

If I browse to the https url for the service it gives me the mex description page but if I browse to the http site for the service I get;

"Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]."

Comment: "Am I missing something?" - Maybe a longer description than "problems making it work". An error-message? A behavior?

Comment: good point, sorry about that. have added the error message I'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't even see the service over http, then that would explain why Silverlight cannot connect to the http service.

Make sure that in your service you define both an HTTP and an HTTPS endpoint.  Posting the .config file for your service may be helpful if possible.

Here is a related SO question [Can a service have multiple endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283/can-a-service-have-multiple-endpoints)

If you can see the service description for both http and https just through the browser, then you can try to get Silverlight to connect to either service.